# Click a link to add product but stay on same page

Tags: javascript, php, function, click, preventdefault

I have a column of product links in my mySQL database and am trying to get the user to add multiple products in his/her cart and not redirect to the cart when adding a product each time. For some reason, my cart is not updating when the user clicks the link. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? $producturl pulls the link from the database. I would like the link to trigger but stay on the page.

```
    <?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$tube1->Tube1));
    if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){  
echo '<span id="shop">Add Cart NoRedirect</span>';
}
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#shop', function (event) {
 $.post( '<?php echo $producturl[0]->URL; ?>' );
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
alert('Product has been added to cart');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want done here. Where is the code to your cart that is not updating? What do you mean by "...like the link to trigger..."?

Comment: I have links that look like: www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1127. That link adds the product to the cart but will redirect the user to the cart for checkout with that item added. I'm trying to add an option so that the user can add multiple products to the cart and go there when he/she chooses.

Comment: use the `jQuery.post` callback feature to display the alert message (and any other debug information from the server) to see what is goiung on

Comment: Inserting jQuery.post callback into my code won't load the page anymore.

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#shop', function (event) {
 $.post("example.php", { comment: "my comment" }, function() {
    alert("success"); })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete");
  });
});
</script> `